# Can I boot Windows 10 installed on a SATA SSD/HDD from USB3 via SATA to USB adapter?

Tags: windows-10, boot, usb, sata

First of all I'm not trying to clone.

I just have a laptop with a dead internal SATA port.  The drive is still alive and I want to boot via a USB3 adapter.

It gets part way through the boot when it blue screens with "inaccessible boot device".

Weird seeing that the boot has already successfully started.

I get the impression the drive and bus are hard coded into Windows like in NT and moving the drive to another bus is a no no!

Does anyone know what needs to be modified in order to complete the boot and allow the OS to find the boot drive that it was initiated from?

I have another system I can use to make modifications if I knew what they were.

Comment: it *MAY* depend on the USB to SATA adapter *chipset* - if it's JMicron, you're probably not going to have a good time :p

Comment: though, to be honest, I don't think windows runs all that well off a USB drive

Comment: See [Using Rufus To Create Windows To Go USB Drive](https://www.intowindows.com/rufus-to-create-windows-to-go-usb-drive/).

Comment: @harrymc Windows To Go wouldn't be recommended, as you can run Windows just fine off a USB connection, it's simply never recommended because if the USB connection on either end is bumped, it can result in a crash, data loss, and file corruption. It's fine for a temporary purpose, but wouldn't be recommended for regular usage. I've applied a WIM to a USB partition plenty of times and it runs just fine, there's simply a far greater chance of the aforementioned since a USB connection on either end isn't as stable as a SATA connection

Comment: Does it ever try to auto-boot to WinRE? It should after two failed boots. If WinRE isn't accessible, boot a Windows install USB while the drive is connected via USB3, press `Shift`+`F10` once the GUI loads, then `BooRec /FixMBR && BootRec /FixBoot && BootRec /RevuildBCD` _(if UEFI, remove `&& BootRec /FixBoot`)_. Reboot and try booting from the USB3 adapter

Comment: After a few boot attempts it enters automatic repair mode and then hangs at Attempting repairs.  I am never given an oportunity to chose other options.

Comment: I wonder if while the internal SATA port was dying, it also caused a problem with the disk. Try to create a standard boot media from Microsoft and see if it can boot.

Comment: Disk is OK I have installed it in another laptop and it boots fine!